# How to send contact form without changing the page altogether

Tags: php, css, contact-form

I want the Contact Form to be replaced with message "Your message has been sent!" without changing the page like in [the case which I show here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5O7W2PIpII).

This is my code: jsfiddle.net/g1o79t49/1/

Comment: include the html for your page in the bottom of your php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1° METHOD**

Redirect your php script to the contact page when the email was sent, then show "Your message has been sent!" on it.

This is an example:

send_mail.php

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    header('Location: ./contact.php?msg_sent=true');
}else{
    header('Location: ./contact.php?msg_sent=false');
}
?>
```

contact.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>...</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
if ($_GET[msg_sent]=='true') {
    echo "<div class="someClass">Your message has been sent!</div>";
}elseif ($_GET[msg_sent]=='false') {
    echo "<div class="someClass">An error occurred sending your message.</div>";
}else{
?>

<form method="POST" action="./send_mail.php">
...
</form>

<?php } ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**2° METHOD**

USE AJAX.

Do something like this:

```
<form id="contactForm1" action="/your_url" method="post">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#contactForm1');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Your message was sent!');
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I made another video (watch?v=Hiz_GMkPUyQ) where I added header('Location: ./your_contact_page.php?message_sent=true'); to the BEGINNING (not end) of my php file and I am redirected to my contact page whcih is cool but still question rematins: how to make the whole contact form disappear and make "Your message has been sent!" in the place of where contact form was?

Comment: Maby I need to make another "custom" return page (contact page2.html) where I will remove the whole form and just write a <p> paragraph saying Your message has been sent in place of the contact form. So instaed of writhing index.html here Location: ./index.html?message_sent=true I will make custom index2.html and in my php paste index2.html in location like this Location: ./index2.html?message_sent=true

Comment: **FIRST OF ALL** you have to put the `header('Location: ./index.php?message_sent=true');` at **THE END** of the file otherwise it bypass the rest of the script. And you have to **remove all the lines with 'echo'** in your kontakt1.php otherwise the `header('Location: ./index.php?message_sent=true');` doesn't works. I edited my answer, you have to put your contact form where is "PUT HERE YOUR CONTACT FORM SCRIPT". Moreover you have to rename the kontakt.html in kontact.php (or index.php) otherwise the php script not run.

Comment: Edited my answer. Now you have a complete example. Can you vote my answer? ;)

Comment: I will vote your answer. Is it necessary to add " ./ " before linking to anthing ?

Comment: no, it's not necessary

Comment: I vote your answer. I made a video showing my failed attempt to implement the code you posted (as an update) at the beginning of your answer. I can't make it work. watch?v=a8YS5OtGXLQ  The message "Your message has been sent!" does not appear after the email has been posted.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. In contact page you have to replace `$_GET[message_sent]` with `$_GET[msg_sent]`. I also edited my answer ;)

Comment: Ha! It works! Bonus points for you my friend! Now I will need to configure it so that "What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)" window works again but I will manage to do it myself

Comment: Best answer? :D Because you can't vote :(

Comment: Ok, I clicked the check mark